# The Money bot not adding earnings that was made discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

So I followed this youtube tutorial, and did this"

```
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 6.0, commands.BucketType.user)
async def work(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    
    users = await get_bank_data()
    
    user = ctx.author
    
    earnings = random.randrange(1000)
    
    await ctx.send(f"You worked on cleaning a toilet, got yourself covered with toilet water and poo, but you managed to get $ `{earnings}`")
    
    wallet_amount = users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"] + earnings 
    
    with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
```

This used to have a `"+="` and it didn't work, my friends said it would be like `x = a + x`, it made sense and I decided to make it into a `+`, however, now it does not add the earnings amount. What do I have to change? A lot of my other similar codes have the same problem.

Comment: What di you mean it's not adding it? When you print wallet_amount does it not change?

Comment: Yep, the wallet_amount stays the same

Comment: Are you trying to change the value in `users`? Because if so, creating and discarding a local variable called `wallet_amount` is not going to help with that.

Comment: I see two problem - first: it should be `users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"] += earnings`. Second you run `users = await get_bank_data()` to get data from somewhere and it may replace new value with old value - but we don't know what you have in this function. Maybe you should create similar method `set_bank_data(users)`

Comment: `it didn't work` is the most useless information. If you get error message then show it in question. We can't run your code, we can't see your full code, and we can't read in your mind. You have to describe all details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

It seems `json` keeps integer key in dictionary as a string so I had to put back `str()` to `users[str(user.id)]`

---

I can't test your code but it should need simply

```
users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"] += earnings
```

But this `user.id` may not exist in `users` so you should check it and create wallet with `0`

```
if user.id not in users:
    users[str(user.id)] = {"Wallet": 0}
    
users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"] += earnings
```

---

**EDIT:**

Question is also what you do in `get_bank_data()` because it assigns value to `users = ...` and it may replace data and it may remove new values.

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working example with commands `!work` and `!wallet`.

If it can't find `bank.json` at start then it creates it.

```
import os
import random
import json
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks


TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.event
async def on_connect():
    print("Connected as", client.user.name)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready as", client.user.name)


async def get_bank_data():

    with open("bank.json", "r") as f:
         users = json.load(f)

    return users

@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 6.0, commands.BucketType.user)
async def work(ctx):
    #user = ctx.author
    user_id = str(ctx.author.id)

    users = await get_bank_data()

    earnings = random.randrange(1000)

    await ctx.send(f"You worked on cleaning a toilet, got yourself covered with toilet water and poo, but you managed to get $ `{earnings}`")

    if user_id not in users:
        print('[work] Create wallet for:', user_id)
        users[user_id] = {"Wallet": 0}

    users[user_id]["Wallet"] += earnings

    with open("bank.json", "w") as f:        
        json.dump(users, f)

@client.command()
async def wallet(ctx):
    #user = ctx.author
    user_id = str(ctx.author.id)

    users = await get_bank_data()

    if user_id not in users:
        await ctx.send("You don't have wallet. Try !work")
    else:
        wallet_amount = users[user_id]["Wallet"]
        await ctx.send(f"You have $ {wallet_amount} in wallet")
    
# --- start ---

if not os.path.exists( "bank.json"):       
    print("[START] Create empty 'bank.json'")
    users = dict()
    with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Thank you, the user.id part is above in the file. Ill try this out

Comment: Here is what I have in get_bank_data:
```async def get_bank_data():
    with open("bank.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
  
        return users```

Comment: it seems that you load again what you wrote after update. Problem can when two person will try to change file at the same time. They one person may overwrite change made by other person. It could be safer to load it only once - at start - and save it after every change. Or you should use some database which should save ony new updated data.

Comment: So what exactly do i do in this case?

Comment: Also with the code you answered, it still didn't do anything

Comment: do you get any message when you put `print()` in `work()`? I built working code to test it and for me main problem is `@commands.cooldown` which block function. So your problem can be totally different then `"+="`.

Comment: it seems `json` keeps integer key in dictionary as a string so it could also makes problem and I had to put back `str()` to `users[str(user.id)]`. I put minimal working code in answer.

Comment: I have a similar piece of code similar to this on a level system and the problem seems to be "+=", but ill try the str option

Comment: `+=` can't be problem - probem can be only how you keep data. If you assign result to `wallet_amount` then it doesn't change value in `users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"]` and you get the same value next time. You have to assign to `users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"]` and `+=` does it. Other problem make JSON. Normally you could use number as `key` in dictionary but JSON converts `key` from number to string and if you read JSON then you get dictionary with strings as keys  and using integer as key you add value to new object in dictionary and you don't have full value.  - `user_id = str(ctx.author.id)`

Comment: The problem is that "+=" gives me an invalid syntax, and by removing the =, it would at least get the bot to run

Comment: if you remove `=` then you add value but you don't assign new value to variable and variable still have old value - so it is useless. And if you get error the show it in question. And check what you have on both sides of `+=` - use `print()` and `print(type(...))` for this. Maybe you use two different objects which can't be added with `+=`. I don't have this problem with code in my answer.

Comment: So I end up replacing the whole get_bank_data and the work command, and it seems to work fine now, thank you for your help